# PostgreSQL: convert data of a column as array of floats to array of decimal

Tags: arrays, postgresql, type-conversion

How can I convert a column containing array of floats (or strings) to an array of decimals in PostgreSQL?

I have tried with pgAdmin 6.6, but for the column in question it shows me no data type ("Definition" -> "Data type:" -> "Select an item" -> No options)

Any idea is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have tried:

```
update mytable set new_column = old_column::Decimal(14,8);
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type numeric[] to numeric
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unnest the existing column `old_column` into individual values and cast those as the new type in a CTE. Then use array_agg to build the individual values into an array of the new data type. Something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7cdcee28546bf58673e03e50a6029d41))

```
with newagg (id, col) as
     ( select id, unnest(old_column)::decimal(14,8)
         from mytable
     )
update mytable ma
       set new_column = (select array_agg(col) 
                           from newagg na
                          where na.id = ma.id
                        ) ;
```

Note: This requires a unique column (here  `id`) to ensure the Update row matches the original source row.